# ...Begin running ahead happily scouting

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

In the sentence below, what is the exact role of *scouting* (adverb phrase, gerund, etc.) and what is the adverb *happily* for?

> Ricky began running ahead happily scouting the bushes.

Comment: Can you please check the dictionary for the meaning of those two words, and then, if you still don't understand the sentence, edit your question to explain which aspects of the definitions you don't understand.

Comment: I metioned above that I need the fucntion of words in the sentence above, knowing the definitions.

Comment: @deadrat I'm not proud...

Comment: @deadrat abashed, I abase my head and efface my comment.

Comment: @MaxWilliams And in rhyme, no less. A comment upvote for that alone. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Happily* is an adverb, and in your sentence its role is to modify a verb. But the sentence is ambiguous without punctuation.

> **[1a]** Ricky began running ahead happily, scouting the bushes.
>   **[1b]** Ricky began running ahead, happily scouting the bushes.

In 1a, Ricky is running in a happy manner; in 1b, he's scouting in a happy manner.

*Scouting the bushes* is a participial clause with present participle *scouting*. It's function is that of a nominative absolute, so-called nominative since it applies to the subject of the independent clause *Ricky*; so-called absolute because it's not closely related to the syntax of the independent clause.

As often happens with this type of construction, the absolute in part modifies the subject (i.e, it helps describe Ricky) and in part modifies the predicate (i.e., it tells us in what manner Ricky was running or scouting).

Comment: It doesn't look ambiguous to me.  Without a comma I would take it to be your [1b].